# what's "?t=" in the socketIO url

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm new to socketIO, and I found everytime when connecting to a node server through socketIO, it generated an uri looks like

```
https://XXX:8080/socketIO/1/?t=XXXXXXXXXXX
```

does anyone here know what's this "?t=XXXXX" part? it's a bunch of numbers, is it time tag or just something else generated randomly by socketio?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: it's just a cachebuster

Comment: so can i generate a random t?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's a timestamp](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-client/blob/0.9.17/lib/transports/xhr.js#L152) using the [current time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) in milliseconds:

```
var req = io.util.request(this.socket.isXDomain())
  , query = io.util.query(this.socket.options.query, 't=' + +new Date);
//                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`+new Date`, with a [unary `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_%28.2B%29), acts the same as [`new Date().getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime).

```
console.log('t=' + +new Date);
// t=1402683183470
```

Such parameters are typically added to try to avoid receiving responses that were cached by the browser.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i have some problem connecting to the socket from my android now, so I'm trying to figure out what can i do.